# WP7 SystemTray Fields/Methods Query

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, system-tray

I've been working with the [`SystemTray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626537%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) in WP7, but I'm a little confused if there's a difference between using a field to set a value or using a method?

For example, I can write:

```
SystemTray.ProgressIndicator = myProgressBar;
```

Or I can write:

```
SystemTray.SetProgressIndicator(this, myProgressBar);
```

Both of these work, but it seems a little redundant to have both (though I'm new to C#, so perhaps I'm missing something).

Does this just boil down to personal preference, or is there a good reason to use one way or the other? Sorry in advance if this is obvious; I'm just new and curious.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626537%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) more carefully:
`SystemTray.SetProgressIndicator` Method:
Sets the value of the ProgressIndicator attached property for a **specified phone application page**.
`SystemTray.ProgressIndicator` Property:
Gets or sets the progress indicator on the system tray on the **current** application page.

Comment: Thanks 0x49D1! I missed that as I've always been working with the current page. Thanks for pointing out the difference.